# Update Datasource of a gridview on GridRowCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How to update the datasource of a gridview on rowcommand. 
I have a TemplateField as button and in Datasource have a Bool variable IsClicked to record if the button has ever clicked.
I need to update the IsClicked value to true if the button is clicked and assign the updated datasource to the grid.

Comment: hows the datasource bound? please show some code on what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
void GridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //You can try with Command Name.
    if(e.CommandName=="Update")
    {
      .....  
    }

    //You can also try with sender parameter
    var control = (Button)sender;
    if(control.Id = "YourId")
    {
      .....
    } 
}
```